# jQuery: Finding the correct element to remove a class

Tags: jquery

Ok, somehow I'm just not able to figure out how to make this work, it can't be that difficult.

I have a plain old navigation, like so:

```
<ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="men-trigger">Men's</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="women-trigger">Women's</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="coed-trigger">Coed</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="all-trigger">All</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I need to add a class to the clicked element (which I know how to do):

```
$('.men-trigger').click(function() {  
   $(this).addClass('active');   
});
```

What I'm having problems with is how to remove the class `active` from a nav item when another nav item is clicked.

I've tried something like but it doesn't work:

```
$('.men-trigger').click(function() {  
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).prev().siblings().find('active').removeClass('active');
});
```

I've tried using `.parent().siblings().children();`, `.parents(ul).find('active');` and I still haven't been able to make it work.

I created a **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rzea/Vyeaf/3/)** of this.

NOTE: Each nav element needs to have its own class because I'm doing something else in the script, here I'm just showing you the problem I'm having.

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$('.men-trigger').click(function() {  
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

Also, you can join all those function with the "ends-with" selector:

```
$('[class$="trigger"]').click(function() {  
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

And since they are nested anchors inside li's, you'll probably have to to:

```
$('[class$="trigger"]').on('click', function() {  
    $(this).addClass('active').parent('li').siblings().find('a').removeClass('active');
});​
```

which also adds `on()` as the preferred way to bind event handlers if using jQuery 1.7+

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vyeaf/15/)

Comment: much more elegant than my solution: +1

Comment: would it make any difference in specifying `siblings(".active")` to only select the active ones?

Comment: I don't really think so, as it probably takes just as long to filter that selector as it does to just remove the class on all elements if they have it.

Comment: @adeneo Oh! I wasn't too far off when chaining the methods. I like your answer because all the additional helpful information. "One Function To Rule Them All" :). It worked great. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.men-trigger').click(function() {  
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

assuming you're using the class active only for the nav elements

Comment: Oh boy, I think your solution was the most obvious one. Sometimes I over think things too much. This worked great. Gave you an upvote, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use closest to find the parent element.  And your find didn't have the "." before active.

```
$('.men-trigger').click(function() {  
    $(this).closest('ul').find('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: You're right, I missed the "." before the active. This worked great. Gave you an upvote, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).children('a').addClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().children('a').removeClass('active');    
});​
```